# slapd won't start (due to missing certificate?)

Tags: ssl-certificate, ldap, openldap, certificate

I'm trying to setup a OpenLDAP server on a CentOS 7.5. Following [this](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html) guide seemed to work very well until something went wrong (LDAP-password wasn't accepted any longer) due to a server crash. I couldn't even figure out what the problem actually was, so I tried to reset all OpenLDAP things on the system by executing this lines:

```
systemctl stop slapd
systemctl disable slapd
yum -y remove openldap-servers openldap-clients
rm -rf /var/lib/ldap
userdel ldap
rm -rf /etc/openldap
```

Unfortunately the last line deleted some certificates I think and so I can't start the slapd.service anymore. When I try

```
systemctl start slapd.service
```

I get an error quoting:

```
Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

"journalctl -xe" tells me this:

```
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap sudo[6291]: tigraebe : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/pki/tls/certs ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start slapd.service
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap polkitd[1104]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6292:584482 (system bus name :1.136 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap systemd[1]: Starting OpenLDAP Server Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap runuser[6303]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap runuser[6303]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapcat[6307]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (May 16 2018 09:55:53) $
                                         mockbuild@c1bm.rdu2.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: slapd stopped.
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

The only error I can see is the line with (is that about certs, because I deleted the openldap folder containing the subfolder certs/?):

```
Jun 01 10:40:15 ldap slapd[6316]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
```

But I have absolute no idea how to solve this problem even after spending hours of reading in the internet and trying to do this by my own.

Any hint or advise is welcome, but please remember me using CentOS and not Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `grep TLS /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif`